# Android MySql url of PHP file syntax

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on my Android MySql project and I have made my database on WAMP server. Database name is "nfc_base". Now I want to use PHP script that I wrote and saved in www folder, here is location: D:/wamp_server/wamp/www/create_view.php but I am really confused how to write my string of url of that PHP script in android code. This is example for situation when u have real server:

```
private static String url_all_products = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

My problem is that I can't use this syntax because I am running my app on localhost server (emulator) so if someone knows syntax how to write this string, please help me.
Thank you!

EDIT:
I found solution. U must write listening port of server after ip adress in url, for WAMP server default port is 80, for Xampp is 1234, and everything is working fine.

```
private static String url_all_views = "http://10.0.2.2:80/get_all_views.php";
```

Comment: When you run wamp, your base url start with localhost/site_folder/....

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be :

`private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/YourApp/create_view.php";`

Put your php script into `D:/wamp_server/wamp/www/YourApp/`

And also make sure your local server is running...

Comment: I didn't see that you were using Android emulator. Can you try by changing `localhost` by `10.0.2.2` ?

Comment: Sorry but this is not good answer, u dont need to write name od your app in url string. I fixed problem, thx anyway...

Comment: Ok, then you should post your solution so other people can use it.

Comment: Regarding the name of your app, I believe you if you tried it, but I think it's better to put it anyway. In the url you provided in your example, `android_connect` is the name of the app. If you want to put it on the Web, you will have to add it too, I guess, unless you have your own domain name. Have a good day!